# Calculating ending headcount from beginning headcount

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've calculated beginning headcount of employees using DAX below:

```
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

```
Beginning HC = 

VAR last_date = MAX('Date'[Date])
VAR first_date = MIN('Date'[Date])

VAR begin_hc = CALCULATE (
    COUNT(Table1[EmployeeID]),
    Table1[orighiredate_key] <= last_date,
    Table1[terminationdate_key] >= first_date
)

RETURN begin_hc
```

and i want to calculate `ending headcount`, where current month ending headcount equals next month beginning headcount, e.g. `2021 Feb beginning headcount = 2021 Jan ending headcount`, how can i achieve that?

i've tried:

```
Ending HC = CALCULATE(
    [Beginning HC], 
    NEXTMONTH('Date'[Date])
)
```

but it's not working

sample output as below:

[image]

dataset used: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/HRAnalyticRepository/employee-attrition-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to do it

Since `NEXTMONTH` is not working in this case, I do it by getting end of month of next month and start of month of next month

```
Ending HC = 

VAR last_date = DATE(
    YEAR(EOMONTH(MAX('Date'[Date]), 1)), 
    MONTH(EOMONTH(MAX('Date'[Date]), 1)), 
    DAY(EOMONTH(MAX('Date'[Date]), 1))
)

VAR first_date = EOMONTH(
    MIN('Date'[Date]), 0
) + 1

VAR ending_hc = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(Table1[EmployeeID]),
    Table1[orighiredate_key] <= last_date,
    Table1[terminationdate_key] >= first_date
)

RETURN ending_hc
```